# Drawable.setColorFilter behaves differently on two different android versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

I am trying to create a tab bar using StateListDrawable and Drawable.setColorFilter(int color, Mode mode). I am using a one white image, and change it's color based on the states (pressed, focused).

Here is the code snippet :-

```
private static  StateListDrawable  getStateList(int ID) {
    int statePressed = android.R.attr.state_pressed;
    int stateSelected = android.R.attr.state_selected;
    StateListDrawable lStates = new StateListDrawable();

    Resources lResources = UconnectAccessApp.aa().getResources();

    Drawable lTabDisabled = lResources.getDrawable(ID).mutate();
    lTabDisabled.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    lStates.addState(new int[] {-statePressed,-stateSelected}, lTabDisabled);


    Drawable lTabEnabled = lResources.getDrawable(ID).mutate();
    lTabEnabled.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    lStates.addState(new int[] {stateSelected}, lTabEnabled);
    lStates.addState(new int[] {statePressed}, lTabEnabled);

    return lStates;
}
```

Everything works as expected but only on Nexus 5 running on Android 5.1, but doesn't work on other devices (Tested on galaxy S 5 with Android 4.1.2).

For later I get the base images (white),  and color doesn't change on pressing tabs.

Please let me know if I am missing something and why is there two different behavior on different devices.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello, did you find a fix for the issue till now? I got the exact same issue. I want to tint a LayeredDrawable with a color filter. On API level 21 every thing works just fine but below it does not.

Comment: There is an issue with the DrawableContainer which was fixed for API version 21 and above. For lower version create a Customized StateListDrawable and then use it to set images for selected/unselected states. Here is a link for your reference-  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60183. Let me know if it works for you.